# retrofit 2 with gson: can't parse JSON Android

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson, retrofit

In my Android project i use Retrofit 2 with GSON. My problem is inside of JSON I recieve there is an object for example `"city":{"id":"1","name":"Washington"}` and when user doesn't fill city field server sends me `"city":""` (now city is String). So I can't parse this.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the server code... Retrofit and Gson expect data to be well formed. If you have no control of that, you have to manually parse JSON

Comment: Your backend dev should fix this. Otherwise read about custom type adapters in gson. IMHO, fix in this case  should be done in API

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Get your backend fixed
- Write a custom parser for it

You can register custom parsers with Gson.
Follow the example on the offical site to create one: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization